# Forever Bouncing Python Rocket Ship when using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

The Python version I'm using is Python 2.7.13 on MacOS Sierra, and I'm also using OpenCV 3 with Python.

```
while True:
    frame = read_stream()
    # some manipulation on `frame`
    cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)
```

Here I am trying display frames that are coming from a socket stream. It worked fine the first time, but for whatever reason, the next time when I tried to run it, the Python rocket ship icon in the dock just keeps bouncing up and down and the window just won't open.

[image]

Judging from the logs that I am printing, the frames are coming in and well formed.

What would be a probable cause of this? I just couldn't think of a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> > Note: This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). waitKey(25) will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed. (If you put it in a loop to read videos, it will display the video frame-by-frame)

Presumably, adding waitKey(20) will give you a nice 50Hz stream, but you can fiddle with that value to suit your needs.

EDIT: As you say it worked fine the first time, I might be on the wrong track here. I'll remove the answer if that is the case and we'll look into the definition of the image window "Screen"...

Comment: "a nice 50Hz stream" -- That would be the case if a) `waitKey` waited **exactly** 20ms and b) rest of the loop body happened instantly (0 time). Neither of those is the case, so in practice the rate is going to be less than 50 Hz | The `waitKey` is definitely missing from that little snippet shown, but I'd agree that it's debatable whether that's what's causing the problem OP refers to.

Comment: definitely needs waitkey, though to figure out any other problems if there are more

Comment: You know what, I think you are right. I was quite tired yesterday and for reason I replaced `.waitKey` with `time.sleep` causing it to not work.